# React-Native: Its not working when I run the code from terminal

Tags: react-native

It will not be working when I run the code from the terminal but it's working when I run the code from XCode directly.

**Terminal error logs are like the below,**

> info : Failed to create dir 'folly-2018.10.22.00'Can't create 'folly-2018.10.22.00/folly/tracing/test/StaticTracepointTestModule.cpp'
>
> info folly-2018.10.22.00/folly/tracing/test/StaticTracepointTestModule.h: Failed to create dir 'folly-2018.10.22.00'Can't create 'folly-2018.10.22.00/folly/tracing/test/StaticTracepointTestModule.h'
>
> info tar:
>
> info Error exit delayed from previous errors.
>
> info Unpacking '/Users/FromMac/.rncache/folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz' failed. Debug info:
>
> info -rw-r--r--  1 FromMac  staff  2687604 22 Feb 12:49 /Users/FromMac/.rncache/folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz
>
> info f70a75bfeb394363d2049a846bba118ffb3b368a  /Users/FromMac/.rncache/folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz
>
> info Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

**Finally I got an Error message like the below image**

[image]

Comment: to me it seems like you are having XCODE issues. do you have any simple other project running?

Comment: @Rizwanatta Yes my sample projects are working good